# Are AWS RDS manual snapshots stored incrementally or not?

Tags: mysql, devops, rds

Let's say that I have 100GB RDS database. On Monday I created a manual snapshot of that database. On Friday I did the same. 
I understand that the first snapshot will have the same size as original db. What about the second one? Will it also contain all data or will it only have changes made since Monday?

In other words: are manual snapshots more expensive than automated one (that I think are stored incrementally)?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** : Use automated backups. Only use manual snapshots for long term backups.

The below is not exact science, only speculation unfortunately.

**RDS backups are an AWS secret sauce**. However it seems to leverage MySQL binlogs (hence impossible to disable binlogs;) or Postgres WALs for automated backups and possibly LVM snapshots or other technology for other RDS types. But we'll never know. Rumours also say they are compressed (why wouldn't you if CPU is free but storage isn't:)

**Generally manual snapshots will be more expensive**. Due to the fact snapshots don't have a previous point in time to compare with so yes they would probably be fulls (an EBS "safe" snapshot then files are probably shipped to S3 for cold storage). Also it will be more expensive because you will necessarily use more storage on top of the automated backups. However if you turn off automatic backups to manually manage them, you will probably end up paying more (can't confirm) unless they compress well. Even if you could save a few dollars with manuals, the time spent manually managing these snapshots are probably not worth the effort nor risk unless you plan to keep weekly, monthly and yearly rotation which will inevitably cost you more on the long run. FWIW, what we do with our RDS instances is : 7 days backups + a lambda managing weeklies/monthlies/yearlies (and automatic clean-up / rotation). Yes it cost a fair bit of extra $$ on top.

**As you know, backups are "free"** as long as the total amount of backups and snapshots is less or equal to the total amount of RDS storage (all DB combined). See [Reference](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/pricing/#Backup_Storage). Unfortunately there is no way to know how much your RDS snapshots/backups are using therefore how far you are from paying something.

I hope the above (speculation) will somehow comfort you in your thoughts.